# Database date to object

Tags: groovy

I have a column called mydate in the database, which is character and there is only 1 value :
2010-01-01.Suppose I extract the date and save it into a variable called extractedDate which contains the String value of the extracted date.How can I covert this string into a Date object in the format dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: small remark: Date object isn't in any format. Internal implementation is specific. Can be formatted for output in format You wish, or other

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Date.parse(String format, String dateString)`. Find the documentation here: [Date](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). In case you struggle with the date format String, have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

Date object can't have a specific format, they look like this :

```
<java.util.Date@fa115f45 fastTime=1262620860000 cdate=null>
```

However, when you print/display the date, you can format them:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

String string = "2010-01-05";
def readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
def writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy")
def x = writeFormat.format(readFormat.parse(string))
```

`readFormat.parse(string)` turns the string into a Date object, and `writeFormat.format` turns the DateObject into string with format you set